# How to arrange elements in list by specific order

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My html code Element 3 is custom made divider to split with a logo the navigation menu bar in heading. Same menu in footer widget shouldnt have this element on that place.

```css
#menu-footer-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#menu-item-877 ul li:first-child {
  order: 1;
}

#menu-item-139 ul li:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

li.menu-divider-item:nth-child(3) ul li:nth-child(3) {
  order: 6;
}

#menu-item-140 ul li:nth-child(4) {
  order: 3;
}

#menu-item-880 ul li:nth-child(5) {
  order: 4;
}

#menu-item-881 ul li:nth-child(6) {
  order: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-footer-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-footer-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-877" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-877"><a href="link1">Element1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-139"><a href="link2">Element2</a></li>
    <li class="menu-divider-item">
      <a href="link3" rel="home"><img src="Element 3 image path" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="Emojistore" width="80" height="21"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140"><a href="link4">Element4 <span class="cart-count">0</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-880" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-880"><a href="Link5">Element5</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-881" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-881"><a href="Element6">Element6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When i run this, everything stays same. If i dont select List (ul) with selector, everything works fine, but then other lists in the WordPress theme doesnt look as they should be.

Comment: target the ul class or id instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is incorrect. See below a correct version.

```css
#menu-footer-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#menu-footer-menu li:nth-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}

#menu-footer-menu li:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

#menu-footer-menu li:nth-child(3) {
  order: 6;
}

#menu-footer-menu li:nth-child(4) {
  order: 3;
}

#menu-footer-menu li:nth-child(5) {
  order: 4;
}

#menu-footer-menu li:nth-child(6) {
  order: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-footer-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-footer-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-877" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-877"><a href="link1">Element1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-139"><a href="link2">Element2</a></li>
    <li class="menu-divider-item">
      <a href="link3" rel="home"><img src="Element 3 image path" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="Emojistore" width="80" height="21"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140"><a href="link4">Element4 <span class="cart-count">0</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-880" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-880"><a href="Link5">Element5</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-881" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-881"><a href="Element6">Element6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```